# Unable to locate package mailer

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python program that has mailer and running into following error,I tried to install mailer using apt-get as below but again running into error..how to get the mailer module?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myyler.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mailer import Mailer
ImportError: No module named mailer
```

Error:-

```
<terminal>sudo apt-get install mailer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mailer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name is `python-mailer`. You can also install the package with Python's package manager, pip

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install mailer
```

Comment: @Zack: You either use one or the other, but not both. There are distribution-specific wrappers around pip that build packages for your system's package manager if you really need that, but saying that pip is a bad idea is just plain wrong.

Comment: But then this post should not be implying that Apt is a bad idea, either. For automated deployments, (finding the name of and) using the corresponding Apt package may be vastly preferable.

Comment: @tripleee: Automated deployments should be done with virtualenv. I'll edit my answer to change the wording, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use pip to install packages :

```
sudo apt-get install python pip
pip install mailer
```

You can also use : `sudo easy_install mailer`

BTW, to install through apt, python packages are named python-* :

```
sudo apt-get install python-mailer
```

Comment: The downside of those `python-` packages is that many of them are outdated.